# How to improve the quality of PDF's viewed with Google Docs Viewer?

Tags: pdf, google-docs, viewer

I have a PDF that has high-quality images that I want displayed with Google Docs Viewer and unfortunately, the quality of the images is not so good. Other than this, this tool is awesome. Is there any way to improve it?

Here's the link to it:
[link removed]

I ended up using [this](http://malsup.com/jquery/media/) with better results.

Comment: http://www.google.com/about/jobs/ :)

Comment: What's the problem with the images? You say they are high-quality; I assume you mean high-resolution? Can you change the PDF itself? Image quality is influenced not just by resolution but also (often) by compression used, but if you can't change the PDF that obviously isn't going to do you much good :)

Comment: Well, if I open the original pdf in adobe they quality is good. When I view them with Google Docs, the quality is about 50% and some details are lost

Comment: A number of applications on Mac (such as the default PDF viewer called Preview) and the majority of the applications to view PDF on tablet have a whole range of compression and advanced image stuff they don't support. Possibly Google Docs is the same. Can you share the document so that it can be looked at?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added the link. You can compare it with the original pdf.